# How do post a Photo to Facebook when a Wordpress post is published?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I have a wordpress site. It is now using the [official Facebook plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/). When a new post is published, an action will be posted to Facebook. The posted message contains a small thumbnail , post title and some description.

But I want to change this approach. I found [Posterous](http://posterous.com) allow user post a photo to Facebook when a post is published.

Does anyone know any Wordpress plugin which can post a photo to Facebook when publishing?

Thanks all. :)

Comment: Do you mean an external photo or a photo from your post?

Comment: a photo from the newly published post.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this wordpress plugin http://www.nextscripts.com/